# getJSON API works on localhost but not on webserver

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, webserver

I want to build a web app which shows the weather of a city (via userinput). I have three files (index.html for getting userinput, index2.html for getting the data and displaying it and a css file). The problem is that when i run the website locally via the file path in chrome, it works as it should. But when i upload the files on a webserver then the $.getJSON function is not executed. It worked well the first few times but then i made changes it doesnt work anymore. It doesnt work when I even remove some code and just test the basic function. Locally it works with the same code perfectly. I did some debugging and noticed that everything is executed except the getJSON API...

Heres the index file:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> </link>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>


    <body id="page1">
    <center>
    <img src="sun.png" alt="Loading Screen" id="Icon" style="width:100px;height:100px;">

    <h1>WeatherPro</h1>

    <form action="index2.html" method="GET">
    <input type="text" id="input" name="keyword" placeholder="City">
    <br>
    <button type="submit" id="submit">Get Weather</button>
     </form>

     </center>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Heres the second file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Weatherinfo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> </link>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/js/all.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    function openSlideMenu(){
    document.getElementById('menu').style.width = '250px';
    document.getElementById('content').style.marginLeft = '250px';
    }
    function closeSlideMenu(){
    document.getElementById('menu').style.width = '0';
    document.getElementById('content').style.marginLeft = '0';
    }

    function doPrint(){

        const queryString = window.location.search;
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
        const newName = urlParams.get('keyword');

        var link= "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+newName+"&APPID=myAPI";
        $.getJSON(link,function(json){

        var temperatur=json.main.temp;
        temperatur= temperatur - 273.15;
        var roundtemp= Math.round(temperatur*10)/10;
        document.getElementById("TempID").innerHTML = roundtemp;


         });
        }
       </script>

       </head>
       <body id="page2">

       <div id="content">

     <span class="slide">
      <a href="#" onclick="openSlideMenu()">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
     </span>
      <div id="menu" class="nav">
      <a href="#" class="close" onclick="closeSlideMenu()">
        <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
        </a>
      <a href="#">Change Units</a>
      <a href="#">Turn tips on/off</a>
      </div>
     <center>

     <h1 id="Mainheader"> Loading</h1>


      <img src="Loading.png" alt="Loading Screen" id="Icon" style="width:200px;height:200px;">

     <style type="text/css">
      dt, dd { display: inline; }
      </style>

     <p id="TipID">Loading </p>

     <dl>
      <dt>Temperature:</dt><dd id="TempID">Loading</dd> 
     </dl>

      <p id="Tips"> Loading </p>

    <script> 
    doPrint();
    </script>

   </center>
   </body>
   </html>
```

and the css:

```
body {
background-color: #F9CDF4;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
.nav {
height: 100%;
width: 0;
position: fixed;
z-index: 1;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: #D81B60;
opacity: .9;
overflow-x: hidden;
padding-top: 60px;
transition: 0.7s;
}

.nav a {
display: block;
padding: 20px 30px;
font-size: 25px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #ccc;
}
.nav a:hover {
color: #fff;
transition: 0.4s;
}
.nav .close {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 22px;
margin-left: 50px;
font-size: 30px
}
.slide a {
color: #000;
font-size: 36px;
}
#content {
padding: 20px;
transition: margin-left 0.7s;
overflow: hidden;
width: 100%;
}


h1 {
color: navy;
font-family: "Segoe UI";

}

p {
color: #D81B60;
font-weight: bold;
}


dt {

text-align: right;
color: navy;
font-weight: bold;

}


dd {

color: #D81B60;
font-weight: bold;

}
```

Comment: when you say "$.getJSON function is not executed." - is there an error in the console? Can you see the call in the network tab?

Comment: One question would be if you are running the page over https.  I noticed some of the imports are https, while the ajax is http.  Could be a refusal due to mixed content on a https site

Comment: not executed in the sense of: i put document.write("x") in various parts of the code to see where it still appears, and it didnt appear when i put it after the getJSON line. AND the site is served over HTTPS and i noticed that it works on my iphone in safari which uses http but not on other browsers which use https. But i dont know why my safari browser accesses it over http....

Comment: That means the callback isn't executed not the `getJSON` function. Look in the Console: Are there errors? (I'd expect cross origin errors). Look at the Network tab: Is the request made? Does it get a response?

Comment: Im new to web development, I dont know how to debug properly, i only used editors like notepad++ to write the code

Comment: Just take a look at the console and see the well explain error **`The page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=null&APPID=myAPI'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`**

Comment: how do i look in the console?

Answer (score 0):

**const urlParams** is undefined.

I never used **new URLSearchParams(queryString);**, so I'm not sure how it works, but it doesn't work in my beta version of chrome.

You can do it this way without using urlSearchParams.

```
function getWeather(){
    const prams = window.location.search.replace('?','&').split('&');
    const keyword = prams.filter(v => v.indexOf('keyword') > -1)[0].split('=')[1];
    if(keyword){
        var link= "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+keyword+"&APPID=myAPI";
        $.getJSON(link,function(json){
          var temperatur = json.main.temp;
              temperatur = temperatur - 273.15;
          var roundtemp = Math.round(temperatur*10)/10;
          document.getElementById("TempID").innerHTML = roundtemp;
        });
    }else{
        // keyword notfound
    }
}
getWeather();
```

Here is the working repl.it (https://repl.it/repls/SaneRustyMemwatch)

---

If you need to get another value you can just change the keyword line to something like this:

```
const units = prams.filter(v => v.indexOf('units') > -1)[0].split('=')[1];
```

If you are going to use it to query a lot of different values, I would turn it into its own function.

```
function urlQuery(str){
    const prams = window.location.search.replace('?','&').split('&');
    return prams.filter(v => v.indexOf(str) > -1)[0].split('=')[1];
}
var keyword = urlQuery('keyword');
```

Answer (score -1):

OK I found the solution, the var link of the web service had to be over https and not http.